# Meteor : way to specify icon and launch screen of an app?

Tags: cordova, meteor, icons, splash-screen

I would like to set an icon and splash screen to my application made with meteor + cordova without editing the Xcode project itself… how to do so ?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can make use of the `mobile-config.js` file which must be placed at the root of the project . (available from the 0.9.4) To have an example of this file, the simplest way would be to see how the "localmarket" example made it. Just type:

```
meteor create --example localmarket
```

Then watch the file:

```
more localmarket/mobile-config.js
```

Basically, the file needs to describe the App.icons and App.launchScreens. Here is what it must contain:

```
App.icons({
  // iOS
  'iphone': 'resources/icons/icon-60x60.png',
  'iphone_2x': 'resources/icons/icon-60x60@2x.png',
  'iphone_3x': 'resources/icons/icon-60x60@3x.png',
  'ipad': 'resources/icons/icon-76x76.png',
  'ipad_2x': 'resources/icons/icon-76x76@2x.png',

  // Android
  'android_ldpi': 'resources/icons/icon-36x36.png',
  'android_mdpi': 'resources/icons/icon-48x48.png',
  'android_hdpi': 'resources/icons/icon-72x72.png',
  'android_xhdpi': 'resources/icons/icon-96x96.png'
});

App.launchScreens({
  // iOS
  'iphone': 'resources/splash/splash-320x480.png',
  'iphone_2x': 'resources/splash/splash-320x480@2x.png',
  'iphone5': 'resources/splash/splash-320x568@2x.png',
  'iphone6': 'resources/splash/splash-375x667@2x.png',
  'iphone6p_portrait': 'resources/splash/splash-414x736@3x.png',
  'iphone6p_landscape': 'resources/splash/splash-736x414@3x.png',

  'ipad_portrait': 'resources/splash/splash-768x1024.png',
  'ipad_portrait_2x': 'resources/splash/splash-768x1024@2x.png',
  'ipad_landscape': 'resources/splash/splash-1024x768.png',
  'ipad_landscape_2x': 'resources/splash/splash-1024x768@2x.png',

  // Android
  'android_ldpi_portrait': 'resources/splash/splash-200x320.png',
  'android_ldpi_landscape': 'resources/splash/splash-320x200.png',
  'android_mdpi_portrait': 'resources/splash/splash-320x480.png',
  'android_mdpi_landscape': 'resources/splash/splash-480x320.png',
  'android_hdpi_portrait': 'resources/splash/splash-480x800.png',
  'android_hdpi_landscape': 'resources/splash/splash-800x480.png',
  'android_xhdpi_portrait': 'resources/splash/splash-720x1280.png',
  'android_xhdpi_landscape': 'resources/splash/splash-1280x720.png'
});
```

Moreover as you are providing the path for the files, the files needs to be included into a `resources/icons` and `resources/splash` folder you will put in the root of your project.

[Documentation for mobile-config.js](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/mobileconfigjs)

Comment: i can't edit cause it' less than 6 chars. but the example is now actually called "localmarket", so meteor create --example localmarket

Comment: Correct answer but the icon sizes are incomplete. There are more sizes than just 60x60 and 72x72. Is these all that Meteor supports currently?

Comment: [Here is another updated list](https://gist.github.com/jperl/f8c395b9f0f1056ad890) with references on the official pages. Basically iphone_3x (iPhone6 plus) has been added for icons, the iPad one resized to the [official 76px](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconMatrix.html) (instead of 72px) and 3 new Launch Screens for the iPhone6.

Comment: I updated the answer, of course 60x60@2x = 120x120, so the 5 official icon size are covered by the 60x60 (@1x, @2x, @3x) and 76x76(@1x,@2x)

Comment: work's perfect. Copy the example project and use the config file. Thanks!